# Python BeautifulSoup find element that contains text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="info">
       <h3> Height:
            <span>1.1</span>
       </h3>
</div>

<div class="info">
       <h3> Number:
            <span>111111111</span>
       </h3>
</div>
```

This is a partial portion of the site. Ultimately, I want to extract the 111111111. I know I can do
    `soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "info" })`
to get a list of both divs; however, I would prefer to not have to perform a loop to check if it contains the text "Number".

Is there a more elegant way to extract "1111111" so that it does `soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "info" })`, but also makes it so that it MUST contain "Number" within?

I also tried `numberSoup = soup.find('h3', text='Number')`
but it returns `None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use xpath [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains):

```
root.xpath('//div/h3[contains(text(), "Number")]/span/text()')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can write your own filter function and let it be the argument of function `find_all`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def number_span(tag):
    return tag.name=='span' and 'Number:' in tag.parent.contents[0]

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all(number_span)
```

By the way, the reason you can't fetch tags with the `text` param is: text param helps us find tags whose `.string` value equal to its value. And if a tag contains more than one thing then it is not clear what `.string` should refer to. So `.string` is defined to be `None`.

You can reference to [beautiful soup doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string).